# Using AMD module as an Aurelia ViewModel

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal, amd, aurelia

I was playing with Aurelia and seems pretty nice, I use Durandal for some projects and this definitively suit my needs.

Use the new class definition from EC6 is awesome. But now I'm preparing something in which I need to use a classic AMD modules with requireJs, something like this one:

```
define("testModule",
[],
function() {
    "use strict";
    console.log('testModule loaded');

    var testModule = function() {
        var that = this;

        this.variable = 10;

        that.getVariable = function(){
            alert('function executed ' + that.variable);
        };
    }

    return testModule;
});
```

Following the Aurelia's documentation I found that is possible to use something like the testModule as a ViewModel, in fact that viewModel was used in a Durandal application.

But after some attempts I was unable to get this working.

Any thoughts or approaches that someone has followed to do that?
And most important, it is possible? I think it is but just to confirm that are compatible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been experimenting a bit with that. Here is what we came up with. The work is based on the Skeleton Navigation App:

1. Create a folder `amd` in the projects root.
2. Copy your original Durandal VM (from your example) as is into it.
3. Create a Wrapper VM inside `src` named also `testmodule.js` with this contents:

   ```
   export class TestModule {
     constructor() {
     }

     activate() {
       return System.import('../amd/testmodule').then( (result) => {
         if(typeof result === 'function')
           Object.assign(this, new result());
         else
           Object.assign(this, result);
       });
     }
   }
   ```
4. Enjoy :)

What this does is essentially wrap your original DurandalVM and expose it as a new AureliaVM. Its just a starter and there are definitely certain things to look into like respecting Durandals LifeCycle etc. but it's a good start I guess

Comment: Hi @zewa666 If that works, is really a great workaround to work with starndard amd on aurelia, it is a nice conversion and without much effort, happy to hear that the project is getting bigger and bigger. Looking forward to have a release version of Aurelia.

Comment: I've created a repo https://github.com/zewa666/durelia which should help you with the first steps. Lets see how far we can drive this

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example AMD module](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript/blob/master/skel-nav-require-vs-ts/skel-nav-require-vs-ts/views/welcome.js) that works with Aurelia:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
  var Welcome = (function () {
    function Welcome() {
      this.heading = "Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App (VS/TS)!";
      this.firstName = "John";
      this.lastName = "Doe";
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Welcome.prototype, "fullName", {
      get: function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
    Welcome.prototype.welcome = function () {
      alert("Welcome, " + this.fullName + "!");
    };
    return Welcome;
  })();
  exports.Welcome = Welcome;
});
```

it was actually generated by a [TypeScript source file](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript/blob/master/skel-nav-require-vs-ts/skel-nav-require-vs-ts/views/welcome.ts)

```
export class Welcome {
  public heading: string;
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;

  constructor() {
    this.heading = "Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App (VS/TS)!";
    this.firstName = "John";
    this.lastName = "Doe";
  }

  get fullName() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }

  welcome() {
    alert("Welcome, " + this.fullName + "!");
  }
}
```

you can follow [the sample's instructions](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript/blob/master/README.md#just-use-it---visual-studio-using-requirejs-amd-module-loader) in the GitHub repository to work with the sample.

Comment: Thanks @MikeGraham, seems a good solution but a bit complex to convert, since I saw that the documentation explains that Aurelia works with regular AMD modules out of the box. But at least is a possible way to do it. Many thanks for your input. Great framework