# Using AMD/Require modules with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, durandal, aurelia

We're looking into updating our Durandal app to Aurelia (finally).  Our biggest concern right now is code re-use.  We'll write TypeScript for the view logic, but there's a lot of complex clientside media access (webRTC stuff) that has taken a lot of time to get working as raw `JavaScript` AMD modules.

I've seen questions asked about using AMD ViewModels; I'm asking about using AMD modules within new aurelia viewmodels.

As a simple example, I have a `mediaDeviceScanner.js` module:

```
define(["modules/logger"], function (logger) {
    'use strict';
    const mediaDeviceScanner = {};

    mediaDeviceScanner.scanDevices = function() {
        return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}).then(function(stream) {
            return stream;
        }).then(function(stream) {
            return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (availableDevices) {
                const mediaDevices = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < availableDevices.length; ++i) {
                    const deviceCandidate = availableDevices[i];
                    if ((deviceCandidate.kind === "videoinput") && deviceCandidate.deviceId != "default" && deviceCandidate.deviceId != "communications") {
                        mediaDevices.push({ label: deviceCandidate.label, kind: (deviceCandidate.kind == "videoinput" ? "Camera " : "Microphone ") + (mediaDevices.length + 1), id: deviceCandidate.deviceId });
                    }
                }
                return mediaDevices;
            }).catch(function (error) {
                logger.log(error, logger.logLevels.warning, logger.features.webcam, logger.features.webcam);
            });
        })
    }

    return mediaDeviceScanner;
});
```

What's the happy-path to calling `mediaDeviceScanner.scanDevices` from within an aurelia viewmodel?

In my Durandal vm, I have this:

```
define(["amd/mediaDevices/mediaDeviceScanner"],function(mediaDeviceScanner){
    mediaDeviceScanner.scanDevices().then(function(devices){alert('woot')});
});
```

I'd like to get a gauge on what kind of "reuse costs" there will be before I evaluate "framework shift" costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old question regarding this topic. [Using AMD module as an Aurelia ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335502/using-amd-module-as-an-aurelia-viewmodel)
It essentially boils down to which loader you are using. Aurelia CLI by default uses requirejs but recently got an update to support SystemJS. With that it would be possible to, as described in the referenced question, create wrappers for your existing code. The wrappers could be very thin and maybe even generalized to save lots of boilerplate

--EDIT--
Out of interest I've just quickly tried it with a new CLI Project, based on SystemJS.

1. After scaffolding I've placed your example module in `scripts/amd/media-device-scanner.js`
2. Removed the logger dependency, since its not provided in your example
3. Go to `src/app.js` and inside the constructor add this code:

`System.import('../scripts/amd/media-device-scanner.js').then((result) => {
  result.scanDevices();
}`

Still works like a charm ;)

Comment: Btw. coming from Durandal, you'll might wanna take a look at https://github.com/code-chris/aurelia-knockout as well, in order to support KO bindings and leave your original templates without a lot modificiations